# How to burn an ERC721 nft using my own smart contract?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721

I am creating a smart contract where I want user to burn their nfts they are holding to do something.
Now how do I do this using my own smart contract given they provide the nft address?
Can anyone help me with the code?

We assume it is an burnable nft.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use ERC721 Standard code for your NFT? if not share your code

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is going to work simply.
Because the user will need to approve your contract to manage the tokens and then your contract can burn the tokens on behalf of the user.

For this you either need to provide them a UI to call the approve function or they need to call it from etherscan.

Comment: Okay so for the UI part can you provide the function logic of how to approve the smart contract in the backend?

Comment: Just like any normal contract interaction, using ethers or any library.
the only thing to keep in mind is the approve function must be called by the user so that user becomes msg.sender in the NFT contract.